# Как правильно получить значения всех свойств объекта, используя EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Мне достаточно сложно объяснить в двух словах, в чем именно проблема, прошу дочитать до конца.
У меня есть несколько классов.

Expense.cs

```
public partial class Expense
    {
        public int ExId { get; set; }
        public int CheckId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Catg Catg { get; set; }
        .....
        public User User { get; set; }
        .....
    }
```

Catg.cs

```
public class Catg
    {
        public int CatgId { get; set; }
        public string CatgName { get; set; }
        public SqlHierarchyId HierarchyId { get; set; }
    }
```

User.cs

```
public partial class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
```

Допустим, я хочу получить список всех объектов класса Expense, чтобы вывести его в Datagrid.

```
public List<Expense> Expenses = GetExpences(new ApplicationDbContext());

public List<Expense> GetExpences(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            return (from ex in db.Expenses                    
                    select ex).ToList();
        }
```

И вот тут возникает проблема. Значения тех полей, которые имеют стандартные типы int, string и так далее, возвращаются без проблем.
Но в качестве Catg и User мне возвращаются соответствующие объекты, которые содержат только значения идентификатора, но не само их название.
В ApplicationDbContext описание сущности выглядит вот так. Получается, что значение *name не возвращается.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Expense>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.ExId);

                entity.ToTable("expenses");

                entity.Property(e => e.ExId).HasColumnName("ex_id");

                entity.Property(e => e.Catg)
                .HasColumnName("cat_id")
                .HasConversion(
                    catg => new int(),
                    cat_id => new Catg
                    {
                        CatgId = cat_id
                    });


                entity.Property(e => e.User)
                .HasColumnName("user_id")
                .HasConversion(
                    user => new int(),
                    user_id => new User
                    {
                        UserId = user_id
                    });

...


            });
```

Как вывести именно поля с именами Catg и User? У меня пока только одна идея - создавать дочерние классы, где переопределять поле с кастомного типа на стандартный тип string специально для вывода списка.
Если бы это был простой SQL, дело бы решилось join-ами. Но как правильно реализовать это в моем случае?

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.3.php

Comment: _мне возвращаются соответствующие объекты, которые содержат только значения идентификатора_ - именно это и описано в методах конверсии. Если нужно другое поведение - измените `HasConversion`.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасибо, теперь я знаю, как это называется. Вот только почему-то   код вида `var expenses = db.Expenses.Include(ex => ex.Catg).ToList();` выдает ошибку `InvalidOperationException: Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.` Хотя на вид все просто и по мануалу.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, как преобразовывать идентификатор в int и обратно - все понятно. Но у меня пока в голове не укладывается, как дополнительно задать в конверсии вытягивание связанного значения объекта по его идентификатору.

Comment: Нашел эту статью https://medium.com/agilix/entity-framework-core-expanding-a-column-into-multiple-entity-properties-bd1161170f31, но адаптировать не смог. В статье кастомный тип преобразуется в DateTime, где уже есть поля. В моем же случае в int никаких полей быть не может.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно изменить Expense следующим образом:

```
using System.ComponentModel; //Browsable
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; //NotMapped
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema; //NotMapped

[Browsable(false)] public Catg Catg { get; set; } //чтобы не отображалось в DataGrid
[NotMapped] public string CatgName { get => Catg?.CatgName; } //линкуем имя для отображения в DataGrid
[Browsable(false)] public User User { get; set; }
[NotMapped] public string Username { get => User?.Username; }
```

Я читаю базу данным образом:

```
public List<Expense> GetExpences(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            return db.Expenses //получить сущность Expense
            .Include(p => p.Catg) //включить сущность Catg
            .Include(p => p.User) //включить сущность User
            .ToList(); //вернуть всех Expense
        }
```

PS Не очень понимаю зачем вы так описали Entity и может ли он вернуть связанные сущности и тем более связанные с ними свойства "name", но попробуйте описанный пример.

Comment: Увы, все равно ругается `InvalidOperationException: Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.` А что именно неправильно в описании сущностей?

Comment: Попробуйте не использовать HasConversion, я сам в этом на уровне любителя, но предположу что данный метод ломает связи. Пусть всё будет по-умолчанию, и тем методом что я предложил выводить нужные вам данные.

Comment: HasConversion пришлось добавить, т.к. без этого EF ругался на неизвестный тип `The property is of type which is not supported by current database provider.`

Comment: Контекст оформите следующим образом:
public DbSet<Catg> Catgs { get; set; }
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Expense> Expenses { get; set; } 

перед public SqlHierarchyId HierarchyId поставьте [NotMapped], если его нет в БД
Пусть сначала всё автоматически построит, без ручных указаний имён таблиц и колонок, очень просто и без проблем использовать для описания таблиц - атрибуты для полей и классов

Comment: Вы предлагает заново запусть scaffold-dbcontext? Он же просто строит модели на основе базы, и мне это никак не поможет.

Comment: Так классы не вы писали? Они сгенерированы на основе существующей БД?

Comment: Да, это сгенерированные классы, а я их модифицировал.